# What is the best data type to store youtube id database?

Tags: database, types, youtube, storing-data

What is the best data type to store youtube id database?

p.s. The youtube code (id) has got 11 symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A youtube ID is an ASCII string of size 11. It seems [unlikely that this will ever change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6250619/2213023). So I'd use a fixed length string of 11 chars.