# Using the ID of a YouTube video as ID of a HTML tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Will there be any issue with CSS or jQuery if a YT video ID is used as the tag ID?
As in this example:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0qkIdfa3qY
```

```
<div id="_0qkIdfa3qY"></div>
```

```
$('#_0qkIdfa3qY').html();
```

But consider that the ID [can be anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6180138/1287812) with the the following characters:

> ```
> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-
> ```

I'm not seeing anything in the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) regarding the use of upper/lower cases, numbers or the characters `-` and `_`. I wonder specially about numbers or scores in the beginning of the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help, from the [Selectors 3 Module:](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); **they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit**.

Comment: It's not only that ID, I mean *any* ID. But then if the ID was `-0etc`, it would fall under "a hyphen followed by a digit", no?

Comment: Yes what you said is correct .. I thought I'd just provide a little more info since you didn't link the Selectors module .. which is a little newer

Comment: Well, I think that based on the docs you're linking, that we can safely say **"Yes, you will have issues. Don't use the video ID"**. I've made a slight modification in the Question to make clear that I posted only a random example. And, IMHO, I think you need to re-evaluate the sentence that I will not face issues...

Comment: I agree - thank you clarifying .. I also edited the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably be better off using the data attribute.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0qkIdfa3qY

<div data-videoid="_0qkIdfa3qY"></div> 

$('div[data-videoid=_0qkIdfa3qY]').html();
```